# How can I go about using both transactions and prepared statements with PHP and MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions, prepared-statement

I started off working on my current project looking at it from the data integrity standpoint, so I incorporated transactions into the project. Now that I am getting ready to go live, I am looking at it from a security standpoint, and want to add prepared statements. However I am not sure on how to go about using **both** transactions and prepared statements. In pseudo-code, this is what I have now:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(hostname,username,password,database);
$query = " ... ";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if($result){
    $mysqli->commit();
}
else{
    $mysqli->rollback();
}
```

Looking at information on PHP prepared statements, I get this as the general format:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(hostname,username,password,database);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) echo("failed");
$query = "insert into X (var01,var02,var03) values (?,?,?)";
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))) echo("failed");
if (!$stmt->bind_param('sss',$val01,$val02,$val03)) echo("failed");
if (!$stmt->execute()) echo("failed");
$stmt->close();
```

So, my confusion is where I would integrate both the prepared statements and transactions. Instead of placing the `commit()` after the `if ($result)`, would I place it after the `$stmt->execute()` like so:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(hostname,username,password,database);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) echo("failed");
$query = "insert into X (var01,var02,var03) values (?,?,?)";
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))) echo("failed");
if (!$stmt->bind_param('sss',$val01,$val02,$val03)) echo("failed");
if ($stmt->execute()){
    $mysqli->commit();
}
else{
    $mysqli->rollback();
}
$stmt->close();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `commit` and `rollback` but you never begin a transaction.

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
```

Note that you only need transactions if you are doing modification queries that rely on each other. A transaction rollback will undo any modifications performed in that transaction.

You can nest transactions but that's a bit more complicated.

Comment: I just neglected to add my begin_transaction() here in the post. So, you are saying that if I just have single, independent inserts, updates, and deletes, that I do not need to use transactions?

Comment: No because there is no opportunity to rollback. If the query fails nothing has been changed. If the query succeeds why would you roll it back? You can imagine a scenario where you need to perforum multiple INSERT or UPDATE queries. If one of those fails (for instance because of a constraint) you don't want your database to be in the half-way in between state. You want to undo the modifications that did succeed. That is when you rollback.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Although all of my deletes for this project do have multiple parts that must all succeed, or none of them can. So, should I use prepared statements there, even though I am simply doing a "delete where ID = X"?

Comment: I think you can answer that question for yourself. What does PDO does for you and why is it important?

Comment: I am not using PDO, I'm using MySQLi.

Comment: Sorry, I meant prepared statements.